# Parse Nested Json in Python to Remove Special Characters in Columns

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

Here is my Json File

```
{
    "highest_table": {
        "items": [{
                "key": "Human 1",
                "columns": {
                    "Na$me": "Tom",
                    "Description(ms/2)": "Table Number One on the Top",
                    "A&ge": "24",
                    "Ge_nder": "M"
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "Human 2",
                "columns": {
                    "Na$me": "John",
                    "Description(ms/2)": "Table Number One on the Top",
                    "A&ge": "23",
                    "Ge_nder": "M"
                }
                }
        ]
    }
}
```

The goal is to remove any and all special characters in the column names (or if easier any special character at all in the .json file), and return a .json file. 
My initial thoughts is to convert it to pandas, remove special characters in the column heading and convert it back to a .json file.

This is what I have tried so far. Both of them print a single line only.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

data_file = r"C:\characters.json"

with open(data_file) as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)  

df = json_normalize(data)
```

--

```
data_file = r"C:\characters.json"

df = pd.read_json(data_file)
```

How can I extract the columns, remove special characters and put them back in a .json file ?

Comment: What is creating that JSON? Is that in your control or you just have to put up with this format?

Comment: @roganjosh it is a website server that I retrieve this json from

Comment: Poor API :( You can do this with the `json` module but you'll have to rebuild the whole response unless I'm missing a trick

Comment: So I have to unfortunately put up with this format @roganjosh

Comment: @roganjosh can you kindly provide an example ?

Comment: Working on it :)

Comment: It's not elegant. `"items"` is the repeatable unit here? The fix is custom to the actual JSON so I want to be sure I cover the repeating unit i.e. there's only 1 `"highest_table"` key?

Comment: @roganjosh items is only repeated ones at the top. it is the key and the columns that form the rest of the records

Comment: "Both of them print a single line only." => where ? You're not printing anything in your snippet. If what you're talking about is something like `print(df)`, what you see is the (abridged) internal representation of the dataframe, you have to convert it back to json first => `result = df.to_json(); print(result)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit Q&D - you'll have to provide a complete implementation for `fixkey` but this should fix your problem.

```
import json

def fixkey(key):
    # toy implementation
    #print("fixing {}".format(key))
    return key.replace("&", "").replace("$", "")

def normalize(data):
    #print("normalizing {}".format(data))
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data = {fixkey(key): normalize(value) for key, value in data.items()}
    elif isinstance(data, list):
        data = [normalize(item) for item in data]
    return data

jsdata = """
{
    "highest_table": {
        "items": [{
                "key": "Human 1",
                "columns": {
                    "Na$me": "Tom",
                    "Description(ms/2)": "Table Number One on the Top",
                    "A&ge": "24",
                    "Ge_nder": "M"
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "Human 2",
                "columns": {
                    "Na$me": "John",
                    "Description(ms/2)": "Table Number One on the Top",
                    "A&ge": "23",
                    "Ge_nder": "M"
                }
                }
        ]
    }
}
"""


data = json.loads(jsdata)

data = normalize(data)

result = json.dumps(data, indent=2)
print(result)
```

Comment: Nice, I hadn't spotted that line of attack.

Comment: recursion is the way to go for nested data structures ;-)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers , how about using sub instead of replace. As in , `string = re.sub("!@#$%^&*()[]{};:,./<>?\|~-=_+"]', '', key)`

Comment: @JimmyStack as I mentionned, the `fixkey` implementation is up to you - `re.sub()` is one of the possible solution indeed, depending on your needs and what you find the most appropriate wrt/ maintainability and eventually performances (if that's a concern for your use case). Just note that Python strings have a `translate()` method that might be more effective here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers a question about the second `elif` in your function. specifically `[normalize(item)..` . Can you kindly explain what does that part do. Is normalize calling the function again ?

Comment: Yes, it's a recursive call, that's the canonical way to handle nested data structures. With the source json you posted, it make sures the dicts nested in the "items" sublists are correctly fixed, but it will work for any arbitrary json.  You can read this for more on recursion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

Comment: NB: you can uncomment the couple print calls in normalize and fixkey to follow what happens...

Answer (score 1):

Frankly this is *ugly* but I haven't been able to find a more generic approach. This is very specific to your particular JSON (the problem really needs solving in the API).

```
import json


response = """{
    "highest_table": {
        "items": [{
                "key": "Human 1",
                "columns": {
                    "Na$me": "Tom",
                    "Description(ms/2)": "Table Number One on the Top",
                    "A&ge": "24",
                    "Ge_nder": "M"
                }
            },
            {
                "key": "Human 2",
                "columns": {
                    "Na$me": "John",
                    "Description(ms/2)": "Table Number One on the Top",
                    "A&ge": "23",
                    "Ge_nder": "M"
                }
                }
        ]
    }
}"""

def fix_json(resp):

    output = {'highest_table': {'items': []}}
    for item in resp['highest_table']['items']:
        inner_dict = item['columns']
        fixed_values = {'Name': inner_dict['Na$me'],
                        'Description(ms/2)': inner_dict['Description(ms/2)'],
                        'Age': inner_dict['A&ge'],
                        'Gender': inner_dict['Ge_nder']
                        }
        new_inner = {'key': item['key'], 'columns': fixed_values}
        output['highest_table']['items'].append(new_inner)
    return output



response = json.loads(response)
fixed = fix_json(response)
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, 2 questions, 1) Why do you say the real problem is in the .api ? What is the problem with the api ?. Second question, instead of physically removing the special characters for those three columns, can we make it a loop to the columns and remove the special characters ?

Comment: "Why do you say the real problem is in the .api" => because it returns ugly (even if technically valid) json.

Comment: @JimmyStack 1) because by the time the API you're using has generated the response, the damage is done. It's far simpler for the provider of the data to address this issue (those characters have no logical place in the keys). 2) I'm not confident I could make a more generic solution that can fix an arbitrarily nested structure.

Comment: "can we make it a loop to the columns and remove the special characters ?" => cf my own answer for a more generic solution.